Parameter 'return_direct' of langchain agents not working
I have this reproducible code to setup a simple agent that answer a simple question.
The purpose of this example is to show that the parameter return_direct does not work.
Either it's True or False, the output of the tool will be passed to an LLM.
# Import necessary packages
import pandas as pd
import sys
import os
from dotenv import load_dotenv
from langchain_community.tools import StructuredTool
from typing import Literal
from langchain_core.tools import tool
from langgraph.prebuilt import create_react_agent
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI

sys.path.append("..")

from config import this_dir
load_dotenv(os.path.join(this_dir,".env"))

# Define function to print final output of Agent
def print_stream(stream):
    for s in stream:
        message = s["messages"][-1]
        if isinstance(message, tuple):
            print(message)
        else:
            message.pretty_print()

# Define function that will go into the tool
def get_weather(city: Literal["nyc", "sf"]):
    """Use this to get weather information."""
    if city == "nyc":
        return "It might be cloudy in nyc"
    elif city == "sf":
        return "It's always sunny in sf"
    else:
        raise AssertionError("Unknown city")

# Define the tool
weather_tool = StructuredTool.from_function(
    name = "get_weather_information",
    description="get weather information",
    func=get_weather,
    return_direct=True)

# Initialize the LLM model.
model = ChatOpenAI(model="gpt-4o", temperature=0)

# Define toolkit (only 1 tool in this case)
tools = [weather_tool]

# Define simple system prompt
prompt = "Respond in Italian"

# Define the graph
graph = create_react_agent(model, tools=tools, state_modifier=prompt)

# Define user_question
inputs = {"messages": [("user", "What's the weather in NYC?")]}

# Print messages
print_stream(graph.stream(inputs, stream_mode="values"))

Do you know how to force the agent to return the output of the tool as it is (i.e., without passing the output to an LLM)?

I think I solved my issue.
Instead of setting the parameter "return_direct" into the StructuredTool.from_function() function (which is not working in my case), I changed 1 line of code in the definition of the Agent.
I created my agent using the following class. This is the most basic agent that you can create and it is introduced in a deeplearning.ai training course by Harrison Chase:
https://learn.deeplearning.ai/courses/ai-agents-in-langgraph/lesson/3/langgraph-components:
from typing import TypedDict, Annotated
from langchain_core.messages import AnyMessage
import operator
from langgraph.graph import StateGraph, END

class AgentState(TypedDict):
    messages: Annotated[list[AnyMessage], operator.add]

class Agent:

    def __init__(self, tools, checkpointer, system=""):
        self.system = system
        graph = StateGraph(AgentState)
        graph.add_node("llm", self.call_openai)
        graph.add_node("action", self.take_action)
        graph.add_conditional_edges(
            "llm",
            self.exists_action,
            {True: "action", False: END}
        )
        graph.add_edge("action","llm")
        graph.set_entry_point("llm")
        self.graph = graph.compile(checkpointer=checkpointer)
        self.tools = {t.name: t for t in tools}
        self.model = model.bind_tools(tools)

    def exists_action(self, state: AgentState):
        result = state['messages'][-1]
        return len(result.tool_calls) > 0

    def call_openai(self, state: AgentState):
        messages = state['messages']
        if self.system:
            messages = [SystemMessage(content=self.system)] + messages
        message = self.model.invoke(messages)
        return {'messages': [message]}

    def take_action(self, state: AgentState):
        tool_calls = state['messages'][-1].tool_calls
        results = []
        for t in tool_calls:
            print(f"Calling: {t}")
            if t['name'] not in self.tools:      # check for bad tool name from LLM
                print("\n ....bad tool name....")
                result = "bad tool name, retry"  # instruct LLM to retry if bad
            else:
                result = self.tools[t['name']].invoke(t['args'])
            results.append(ToolMessage(tool_call_id=t['id'], name=t['name'], content=str(result)))
        print("Back to the model!")
        return {'messages': results}

What I had to do was to change the line graph.add_edge("action", "llm") into graph.add_edge("action", END). In this way, if a tool is called by an LLM, the output of the tool will represent the END of the agent process.
It is working at the moment. I hope I didn't break anything else :D

This is not tested in theory it should work since you only have a tool.
First we create a function or a customised function since weather tool uses StructuredTool .
# graph creation process to handle return_direct
def customized_create_react_agent(model, tools, state_modifier):
    # logic for returning the tool's output directly
    def custom_graph(inputs):
        # I am assuming we have a 'messages' key in form a a dic
        user_message = inputs["messages"][0][1]
        for tool in tools:
            if tool.return_direct:
                tool_output = tool.func(user_message.split()[-1].lower())
                return [{"messages": [("tool", tool_output)]}]
        # return to original graph if return_direct is False
        return create_react_agent(model, tools=tools, state_modifier=state_modifier).stream(inputs, stream_mode="values")
    return custom_graph

graph = customized_create_react_agent(model, tools=tools, state_modifier=prompt)

# questions from user
inputs = {"messages": [("user", "What's the weather in NYC?")]}

# Print messages
print_stream(graph(inputs))

If this doesn't work we would use the Union[AgentAction, AgentFinish]
from langchain.schema import AgentAction, AgentFinish

It's not working because the input arg of the tool is "nyc?", with the question mark at the end. So the tool returns "AssertionError: Unknown city". This is caused by the split "user_message.split()[-1].lower()", which I don't understand why I should use that split to get the name of the city. It should come from an LLM call.

Hi, oh I see , the code I provided is a snippet(and I said it is not tested) it is not something that would work out of the box. Ideally you can change it to suit your needs, since you can see the output. I don't have got-4 to test the code, you can modify it. I am just a guide , let me know if you need any more help

Hey @Derek. I think I have found a solution and I posted it as answer. What do you think about it?

@AndreaNeri looks good to me! If it works it will definitely help others with the same problem
